# How do I prevent the SCM CLI accept command from generating projects in .metadata?

Tags: version-control, command-line-interface, rtc

I'm using a batch file to load a workspace repository and accept change sets.

The files in the repository have Eclipse projects.

When I accept a change set, the SCM automatically creates the projects in .metadata:

Windows:

```
C:\Users\[user_name]\AppData\Local\jazz-scm\scratch\0\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources
```

If I accept another change set with changes in Eclipse projects, the SCM tries to create the project in .metadata and throws this error in the log:

> com.ibm.team.filesystem.client.FileSystemStatusException: Status ERROR: com.ibm.team.filesystem.client code=0 There were issues encountered during the updating of the sandbox. null children=[Status ERROR: com.ibm.team.filesystem.client code=0 Unable to open project at [path_of_file]/.project, project with name [project_name] already exists null Status ERROR: com.ibm.team.filesystem.client code=0 Unable to open project at [path_of_file]/.project, project with name [project_name] already exists null]

How do I prevent the SCM CLI accept command from generating projects in .metadata?

SCM CLI version:

```
Build Id: RTC-I20141031-0926
com.ibm.team.filesystem.cli.client, version 3.2.400.v20141016_0123
com.ibm.team.filesystem.cli.tools, version 3.1.800.v20140620_0123
com.ibm.team.filesystem.cli.core, version 3.2.400.v20141011_0139
com.ibm.team.rtc.cli.infrastructure, version 3.1.800.v20140619_0246
```